# What's the best way to declare a bidimensional array of unknown dimensions?

Tags: c++, c++11

I need to declare and store a bidimensional array of strings. I have no way of knowing the size of both dimensions beforehand. C++ requires me to know the size of at least the second array, correct? If so, what's the best way to go about this?

Comment: use [my public domain `Array2D` class](https://github.com/jpreiss/array2d)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As other answers stated, `std::vector<>` is the appropriate collection for the job.

To declare a 2D vector of strings, use:

```
std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> strings;
```

Once populated, you can use the familiar subscript notation to access elements:

```
const std::string& at(strings[i][j]);
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `std::vector`. In fact you should already be doing this even if you know the size, unless you have very good reasons not to.

Comment: Wouldn't you prefer to use new[] instead if you are given a fixed size?

Comment: @RahulManne: No. Hell no. An alternative would be `std::array<T, N>`.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use 'raw' arrays, since you don't know the size. One possibility would be to use the standard container `std::vector`.